# How to Select All Pop3 Messages in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, pop3, select-all

I am using Gmail application in Android 6.0. I have > 777 messages in my inbox. I would like to Select All and Delete them from the pop3 account.

---

How can you Select All Pop3 messages in Gmail Android Application?

Comment: This is older, but I actually don't know that anything has changed: [Is there “select all” functionality in the GMail app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/is-there-select-all-functionality-in-the-gmail-app?rq=1) It has a few suggestions for workarounds but they mostly involve changing your whole email workflow. Bit of a bummer, really.

Comment: @eldarerathis I made this thread duplicate. I opened a bounty in the older thread. I opened a thread in the official Gmail forum here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/vUYFtgPU6Ug;context-place=forum/gmail I hope we can understand why the feature is still missing from the application.