# Select all is missing in mobile version of gmail

Tags: gmail

How can I select all instead of one by one in gmail Android version application. ?

Comment: Related [is-there-select-all-functionality-in-the-gmail-app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/is-there-select-all-functionality-in-the-gmail-app)

Comment: *Only the standard view of Gmail in a desktop browser has select all functions.  The Basic HTML version does not, nor do the Gmail Apps*  from [Gmail Help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gmail/98nB0r6LRHA)

Answer (score 0):

Up to Gmail (android) v5.10, there's no option to select all. Maybe they'll add it later. But you can *empty trash* folder in one go.